# BROWSER environment variable in react npm start does not select custom browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ubuntu, npm, create-react-app

I created a react app with creact-react-app. I launch the app with `npm start`. If I create the `.env` file with

```
BROWSER=google-chrome-stable
PORT=4000
```

The port is correctly configured, but the default browser is always launched. No matter if I sorround the browser with single quotes, double quotes, no quotes, or if `google-chrome-stable`, `firefox` or `chromium-browser` is used. A `npm start` always launches the default browser.

I also tried launching in the command line with `BROWSER` or changind the `start` section of the `poackage.json` file nothing works.

Only `BROWSER=none` works.

I also checked several other SO posts, also reinstalled, etc. nothing seems to solve the issue.

Versions are:

- ubuntu 20.04
- node 16.13.1
- npm 8.1.2
- react 17.0.2
- react-dom 17.0.2
- react-scripts 5.0.0

any hints?

Thank you!

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug.

There is a fix https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/11878 and some bug reports are referenced there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the workaround that worked for me until the cra bug is not fixed.

1. Add the following to `package.json`:

```
    "overrides": {
        "open": "7.4.2"
    }
```

2. Remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`
3. Run `npm install`

This requires npm-cli ver. 8.3 or later. For yarn use `resolutions` instead of `overrides`.

The .env file content that worked for me:

```
BROWSER=chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

Just insert `"chrome": "BROWSER='google chrome' react-scripts start"` in the `scripts`section of your package.json.

Then `run npm chrome`.